# Batch file stops running

Tags: batch-file, printing, cmd

This is my batch file

```
set /p file=<"Z:\Proprietary Tools\Print Center\FileToPrint.csv"

Call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /n /s /o /h /t "%file%"

taskkill /IM AcroRd32.exe
```

This stops running and does not give back control after the second line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `Call`?

Comment: Does it start Acrobat Reader?